# Should we remove 'Sitecore' from tags?

Tags: discussion

This is regarding the question: [How to Add contributors to published sitecore marketplace module](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/115/how-to-add-contributors-to-published-sitecore-marketplace-module), which has been tagged with `sitecoremarketplace`.

I feel like as we're on a Sitecore StackExchange, it's fairly obvious if we would tag it with `marketplace` it would be regarding the Sitecore marketplace.

How are we going to deal with this? Flag as and when these come up?

Comment: I have no problem with removing Sitecore tag, but I think that version tags should exist.   Often configurations, etc. are version specific so having a version would probably be helpful down the road.

Comment: What about Sitecore Commerce? Would just "Commerce" suffice? If it's a product name I'd suggest Sitecore remains.

Answer (score 2):

Several other product-based stack exchange sites have tags with the name of the product in them:

- [Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags)
- [Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags)
- [Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags)
- [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags)
- [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/tags)

It seems that if having sitecore in the tag name can help disambiguate the tag from other meanings, even if those other meanings aren't applicable on the site, then we should keep sitecore in the tag name.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is a good idea.

If someone already used sitecore you can simply edit the question and retag.

Comment: What about issues relating to particular Sitecore versions only? For example `Sitecore-7.5` is okay to use ?